# How to get the class in which the method is declared using jmethod id via JVMTI interface

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jvmti, jnienv

I am writing a custom debugger for JVM using the JVMTI interface's APIs and i need to get the class name in which the method is declared, i get the method id of the method using `error = (*jvmti)->GetMethodName(jvmti,frames[i].method,&methodName,NULL,NULL);` and i am trying to get the class name using `error = (*jvmti)->GetMethodDeclaringClass(jvmti,frames[i].method,&declaring_class_ptr);`

this returns the jclass reference in the declaring_class_ptr, my question is how to convert this to a string which gives the class name?

Comment: the debugger is being written in C

Comment: sorry removing the tag

Comment: I got it for you `:)`

Comment: Thanks.........:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the class name you need to use GetClassSignature, something like:

```
char* name;
jvmti->GetClassSignature(class, &name, NULL);
trace(jvmti, "Class prepared: %s", fix_class_name(name));
jvmti->Deallocate((unsigned char*)name);
```

Comment: i need to get the local variables inside the method and the class and their corresponding values when this method was called, is there a way to do this using JVMTI itself? 

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure. Take a look here, perhaps this will help you a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041177/jvmti-how-to-get-the-value-of-a-method-parameter-from-callback